# Bash: Regex for finding pattern having double quotes

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I am trying to use regex in my shell script to find a substring.

Original string:

```
"relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-enabled="true" scan-interval="0""
```

Trying to find following substring:

```
"scan-enabled="true""
```

Code:

```
str="relative-to=\"jboss.server.base.dir\" scan-enabled=\"true\" scan-interval=\"0\""
reg='scan-enabled.*"'
[[ "$str" =~ $reg ]] && echo $BASH_REMATCH
```

but it is returning,

```
scan-enabled="true" scan-interval="0"
```

Can someone please help on how to search for a pattern involving double quotes using regex?

Bash version: 4.1.2(1)-release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match the entire expression `scan-enabled="true"` or `scan-enabled="false"` then you can try this:

```
reg='(scan-enabled=\"[^"]*\")'
[[ "$str" =~ $reg ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

The variable `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` will match the first capture group match in the regular expression.  In this case, the entire regular expression is contained in parenthesis, so this is the first capture group.

You can explore this regex at this link:

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/nM2hX8/1)

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Tim Biegeleisen. I am trying to use this, reg='scan-enabled=\".*\"'
[[ "$str" =~ $reg ]] && echo $BASH_REMATCH, but it still returns "scan-enabled="true scan-interval="0"
"

Comment: No.  If you use `$BASH_REMATCH` I believe it will always give the entire input string.

Comment: Ohh, Problem is scan-enabled can have any value and I want capture it all. Hence I am using the regex 'scan-enabled=\".*\"'

Comment: What exactly do you want to capture?  Do you want to test for the presence of `scan-enabled` or for a specific value of this property?  If the latter, try using the second part of my answer.

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear. I would like to capture "scan-enabled="true"". if scan-enabled has value of "false", then I would like to capture "scan-enabled="false"".

Comment: thanks. It may have any value, eg. true, false, 11, etc